# Continuous random number generator adding numbers to max - PHP

Tags: php, random, repeat, self-reference

I have a random number generator that spits out a number between 1 and 5. This thing does so every five minutes using a simple  script "random.php". The idea is that the function does so more or less indefinitely.

```
<?php
header("Refresh:1");
$num = rand(1,5);
```

What I want to do is to have another script look at this one, retrieve the $num number and drop that to a $total, and keep doing to until that total reaches 20. Adding up the numbers is not an issue, the problem is to keep getting the new random numbers? What I want to do is along the lines of this but I cannot figure out how:

```
<?php
require("random.php");

$max = 20;
$now = 0;

while ($now <= $max){
    $new = [get new randon number somehow] 
    $now = $now + $new;
    echo "$now<br>";
}
```

I want to solve this in PHP if possible, not interested in JS or CURL solutions at the moment. I need to exhaust this in PHP.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/242137). Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve? In any case, the `Refresh: 1` header is of no use unless you're accessing `random.php` via HTTP (which you aren't). But if it did work, your other script would be functionally equivalent to something like `sleep(f()); echo (20+g())."<br>";`, where `f()` and `g()` are functions that mimic the probable outcomes of your `while()` loop. Why are you trying to do this with two files?

Comment: hi, im trying to make a generator that is spitting out a random number between 1 - 10 every minutes (or so), catch that number and put it into a container, adding to the overall sum. 

so minute 1 the number is 3, min 2 a new number (4) is generated. the total is then 7. minute 3 9 is generated bringing the total to 16... and so on.

from what i understand theres ways of doing this with ajax, but i have no idea where to start with that so i figured id try in php

Comment: Still not sure what you're trying to do, but if you want this to happen in a web page try using Javascript. For example: `<script>var sum=0,timer=setInterval(function(){sum+=Math.floor(Math.random()*10+1); alert("sum="+sum)}, 60000);</script>`. Change 60000 to (*no. of seconds*) * 1000 for a different update interval, and use `clearInterval(timer)` to stop the number updating.

Comment: problem is that i need to fetch the number and use it in a php calc. i have no idea how to get the javascript number back to php on a regular update :(

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation of what you're attempting to do is still completely inadequate. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: ok, let me try this again. so let say you have a website that every 5 seconds displays a new number; 1, 4, 2, 6, 9, 3 ... and so on. all numbers generqted at random between 1 and 10. for every new number generated i want that to be caught and added to the previous number; 1 + 4 = 5. 5 + 2 = 7. that is all. i can do all of this in php except for the random number generator. this is what i need. hope it is clear now.